# force a program to free memory allocated during a function after that function ends (C++)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Is it possible to force a program to free memory allocated during a function after that function ends?

The situation I have is essentially this.  I have a for loop that calls another function and does some things then returns.  This other function (myfunction in the below code) then calls a function I have no control over (otherpersonsfunction in the below code).  Every time my program calls otherpersonsfunction, the memory usage grows and doesn't go back down.  This isn't a problem if otherpersonsfunction is only called once or twice, but if myvector gets very large, then I will be calling it many times (enough to cause the server it was running on to run out of memory at least once).  I have no way of changing how otherpersonsfunction works so what I want to know is if it's possible to force the program to clear the memory allocated during the call of myfunction once that call is completed.  Is there something I could put in the for loop that would accomplish this?

```
for(int j = 0; j < myvector.size(); j++)
{
  //some code, then a function call
  myfunction(myvector.field1);
  //force program to free all memory allocated during execution of myfunction.
  //How do I do this?
}

myfunction(myvector.field1)
{
  //some code, then a function call
  otherpersonsfunction(myvector.field1);
  return;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization is roughly the thing you want to google. or wait for the first answer explaining it :)

Comment: Can't see anything explicitely allocated in your sample? So you don't need to at all perhaps?

Comment: If `otherpersonsfunction` is the cause of the memory growing, then you can't do anything about it without access to modify the code.

Comment: @crashmstr It is, and I was hoping that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Without knowing the real function signatures and what `otherfunction` is supposed to do it is impossible to know if this is solvable or there is a bug in your code or `otherfunction`. Is `otherfunction` allocating something that you are responsible for deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the other function is completely out of your control AND that function is using the standard memory allocator the answer is no. Even if it was technically possible doing so would be unsafe since a pointer to the memory you've forcibly freed may end up saved somewhere and when it is used later all sorts of funny things will happen.

If it is possible to convert the other function to use some custom allocator the answer changes to yes (assuming you validate that pointers aren't saved between the calls; fortunately with the custom allocator other libraries including libc are out of equation hence it is doable).

Answer (score 0):

**If memory is acquired in your function:**
Then follow [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom. The way to achieve this in *most cases* is:

1. Declare variables as locally as possible (on the stack).
2. If you need to place something on the heap (using `new` operator) then use a `unique_ptr` as your first option. `shared_ptr` only if needed. Avoid naked pointers.

**If memory is acquired in somebody else's code:**
There is nothing much you can do, as far as I know, other than getting access to his code and fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate in the function, then deallocate at the end of the function, I recommend using stack  instead of heap variables. It's faster too, but obviously not always possible.

The other option is if you are using C++ 11 to use a try-catch-finally and place your memory deallocation code in the finally cause.

If myFunction returns pointers, you can delete them in the caller. Remember that someone has to have ownership of the memory, it's a bad idea to delete memory from underneath someone else. So if myFunction allocates memory, returns a pointer then goes away and never uses that memory again, you are OK to delete it in the caller.